# github webhook with flask - Github not trigger or not send requset

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, github-actions, github-webhook

I tried to write a flask app that when every time you do a push event to the Github repo it sends a webhook to the flask server. My code for flask app is:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def getGitUpdate():
   #some of code
   return 'hello world'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("0.0.0.0",8000)
```

The way I set up the webhook on Github is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xTFX.png)

It is important to note that the firewall is turned off, and in addition I am using the ubuntu 21.04 operating system.

Comment: try using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) if you running server in localhost

Comment: thank you , But i don't run it on local host, I run it as I wrote in the code